# Class javax.swing.Popup Experiments

Tags: java, swing

I have discovered class `javax.swing.Popup`. I wrote code to test its behavior. Code is shown below. When I run the code, after the `JFrame` is displayed, I click the SHOW button and the `Popup` is displayed. After that I click the HIDE button and the `Popup` disappears. But then if I click the SHOW button again, nothing happens. The `Popup` only appears after clicking the SHOW button for the first time. Also, if I click the HIDE button first, before clicking the SHOW button, then when I click the SHOW button, the `Popup` does not appear.

Am I missing something?
Am I doing something wrong?

I admit I haven't investigated this behavior. I haven't searched the Internet and I haven't looked at the code for class `Popup` nor `PopupFactory`, simply due to laziness and in the hope that someone can explain it to me.

Here is my MCVE.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Popup;
import javax.swing.PopupFactory;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class PopupTest implements ActionListener, Runnable {
    private static final String HIDE = "HIDE";
    private static final String SHOW = "SHOW";
    private Popup popup;

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        String actionCommand = actionEvent.getActionCommand();
        switch (actionCommand) {
            case HIDE:
                popup.hide();
                break;
            case SHOW:
                popup.show();
                break;
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        showGui();
    }

    private void showGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Popup");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JLabel centerLabel = new JLabel("CENTER LABEL", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        frame.add(centerLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JPanel buttonsPanel = new JPanel();
        JButton showButton = new JButton(SHOW);
        showButton.addActionListener(this);
        buttonsPanel.add(showButton);
        JButton hideButton = new JButton(HIDE);
        hideButton.addActionListener(this);
        buttonsPanel.add(hideButton);
        frame.add(buttonsPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        JLabel popupLabel = new JLabel("Popup_Label");
        PopupFactory factory = PopupFactory.getSharedInstance();
        Point pt = centerLabel.getLocationOnScreen();
        int x = pt.x + 10;
        int y = pt.y - 10;
        popup = factory.getPopup(centerLabel, popupLabel, x, y);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PopupTest instance = new PopupTest();
        EventQueue.invokeLater(instance);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Popup.html#hide()

The documentation that you have chosen not to read is very clear that `hide()` disposes of the `Popup` and any further method calls on that `Popup` will result in indeterminate behaviour.

You must create a new `Popup` instance each time.

Comment: That's what I thought. That I need to create a new `Popup` each time I want to display it. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs for hide():

> "Hides and disposes of the Popup. Once a Popup has been disposed you
>   should no longer invoke methods on it. A disposed Popup may be
>   reclaimed and later used based on the PopupFactory."

As such, here is a quick and dirty modified version that works.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Popup;
import javax.swing.PopupFactory;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class PopupTest implements ActionListener, Runnable {

  private static final String HIDE = "HIDE";
  private static final String SHOW = "SHOW";
  private Popup popup;
  private JLabel centerLabel;
  private JLabel popupLabel = new JLabel("Popup_Label");
  private PopupFactory factory = PopupFactory.getSharedInstance();

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    String actionCommand = actionEvent.getActionCommand();
    switch (actionCommand) {
      case HIDE:
        if (popup == null) {
          return;
        }
        popup.hide();
        popup = null; // necessary to avoid using the disposed popup
        break;

      case SHOW:
        if (popup != null) { // it's already showing
          return;
        }
        Point pt = centerLabel.getLocationOnScreen();
        int x = pt.x + 10;
        int y = pt.y - 10;
        popup = factory.getPopup(centerLabel, popupLabel, x, y);
        popup.show();
        break;
    }
  }

  public void run() {
    showGui();
  }

  private void showGui() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Popup");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    centerLabel = new JLabel("CENTER LABEL", SwingConstants.CENTER);
    frame.add(centerLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    JPanel buttonsPanel = new JPanel();
    JButton showButton = new JButton(SHOW);
    showButton.addActionListener(this);
    buttonsPanel.add(showButton);
    JButton hideButton = new JButton(HIDE);
    hideButton.addActionListener(this);
    buttonsPanel.add(hideButton);
    frame.add(buttonsPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    PopupTest instance = new PopupTest();
    EventQueue.invokeLater(instance);
  }
}
```